# Java - Inheritance regarding constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

So, I'm trying to practice my java skills by applying it to some math homework and making a frequency distribution chart using inheritance. In my head, I envision it as a frequency distribution (parent class = FreqDist) that can have multiple "MyStatClasses" (in the form of the MyStatClass array). Each FreqDist has variables that span across all MyStatClasses which is why I put them in the parent class. However, when I call the MyStatClass constructor, my program gets a StackOverflowError. I think this is because the super(s, i) line calls back to the FreqDist constructor and starts over, causing an infinite loop. Assuming this is the case, how would I fix this?

Ideally, I'd like to access my MyStatClass array and grab values that only apply to that MyStatClass, but I cannot get it to work.

```
public class FreqDist {

private MyStatClass[] freqClasses;

private double[] dblValuesArray;
private int intNumberOfClasses;
private double dblMax;
private double dblMin;
private int intClassWidth;

public FreqDist(String strValues, int intNumOfClasses) {
    System.out.println("This is the beginning of the FreqDist constructor...");
    dblValuesArray = getDoubleValues(strValues);
    intNumberOfClasses = intNumOfClasses;

    dblMin = dblValuesArray[0];
    dblMax = dblValuesArray[dblValuesArray.length - 1];

    intClassWidth = (int)Math.ceil((dblMax - dblMin) / intNumberOfClasses);

    freqClasses = new MyStatClass[intNumberOfClasses];

    for (int x = 0; x < freqClasses.length; x++) {
        freqClasses[x] = new MyStatClass(strValues, intNumOfClasses);
    }
}

public double[] getDoubleValues(String strValues) {
    String[] strValuesArray = strValues.trim().split(" ");
    dblValuesArray = new double[strValuesArray.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < strValuesArray.length; x++) {
        dblValuesArray[x] = Double.parseDouble(strValuesArray[x]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(dblValuesArray);

    return dblValuesArray;
}

public int getNumberOfClasses() {
    return intNumberOfClasses;
}

public double getMin() {
    return dblMin;
}

public double getMax() {
    return dblMax;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What are the values? ");
    String values = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("How many classes? ");
    int classes = scan.nextInt();
    FreqDist fd = new FreqDist(values, classes);
}
}

public class MyStatClass extends FreqDist {

    public MyStatClass(String s, int i) {
        super(s, i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does `MyStatClass` need to be a subclass of `FreqDist`?

Comment: I want each `MyStatClass` to have the same properties that come from `FreqDist` while each having their own separate properties on their own.

Comment: You have a loop in your inheritance pattern, which is causing the `StackOverflowError`. Break this loop to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is mostly an issue with a flaw in your design.

From what I understand `FreqDist` is a class that should contain an array of `MyStatClass`. You want them to have the same properties so you make MyStatClass extend FreqDist. However when you call FreqDist it MyStatClass which Calls a new MyStatClass over and over and over.

One way to solve this is to create a new class that has the shared properties you want FreqDist and MyStatClass to have, and have those two classes inherit from said class. Then create separate constructors for FreqDist and MyStatClass.

Comment: Thank you. I'm alright with Java and not that experienced so I appreciate the help. I figured that if something was wrong, it would be my overall design. Definitely something I'll need to work on in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A parent type should never refer to its own subtypes, as yours does. Her the parent initializes subtype instances, which require that each initialize the parent type, which initializes subtype instances, which initialize their parent type, which initializes... KABLOOEY!

Comment: They know this. See their first paragraph.

Comment: So don't refer to the child type in the parent type, as I suggested.